# RestSharp: Deserialize json string

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I have been trying to deserialize return `response.Content` string but in vain. WebApi action returns a modified `modelState` with additional custom errors.

On the MVC side, I tried the following methods none worked:

```
JsonDeserializer deserial = new JsonDeserializer();
  var json = deserial.Deserialize<dynamic>(response);
```

And

```
    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebApiReturnModel>(response.Content);

    public class WebApiReturnModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public ModelStateDictionary ModelState { get; set; }
    }
```

Example of `response.Content` returned:

```
{
    "Message":"The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState":{
        "": ["Name Something is already taken.","Email 'ab@something.com' is already taken."]
            }
}
```

How to get this to work?

Comment: How is `ModelStateDictionary` designed?

Comment: @Amit That is default .Net implementation

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the `dynamic` approach and for me this works:

```
var input = @"{
                ""Message"":""The request is invalid."",
                ""ModelState"":{
                            """": [""Name Something is already taken."",""Email 'ab@something.com' is already taken.""]
                }
            }";

// This uses JSON.Net, as your second snippet of code.
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(input);

// This will get: The request is invalid.
var message = json["Message"].Value;

foreach (var m in json["ModelState"][""])
{
    // This will get the messages in the ModelState.
    var errorMessage = m.Value;
}
```

If you don't know the names of the keys in `ModelState`, you can use a nested loop:

```
foreach (var m in json["ModelState"])
{
    foreach (var detail in m.Value)
    {
        // This will get the messages in the ModelState.
        var errorMessage = detail.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem with `json["ModelState"][""]` is that the key has to be known before it can be used. There has to be a better way.